# Emacs reopen previous killed buffer？

Tags: emacs

Any add-on to reopen the last killed buffer/file? Just like the C-S-t do in firefox.

I know about that recentf-mode can remember the recent visited files history.

Comment: This can't really work in general--what if you had some process running in your buffer? Would it restart the process (and potentially do some side-effect twice) or give you a buffer without a process attached? Neither solution sounds particularly good.

Comment: There is kill buffer hook. It should be possible to build and maintain a list of killed buffers. With the help of this list the recently  killed buffers should be accessible. no?

Answer (score 12):

```
(require 'cl)
(require 'recentf)

(defun find-last-killed-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((active-files (loop for buf in (buffer-list)
                            when (buffer-file-name buf) collect it)))
    (loop for file in recentf-list
          unless (member file active-files) return (find-file file))))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-S-t") 'find-last-killed-file)
```